# Отслеживания трафика который идет через vpn сервер

Tags: vpn

Если я использую рабочий впн-сервер, для просмотра видео и т.д. Так же сижу на заблокированом в стране сайте. Могут ли админы впн-сервера посмотреть историю посещений?

Comment: Если сайт доступен только через https, то не могут. Но сам факт посещения сайта определить ничто не мешает, пользуясь фактом соединения с IP-адресом, принадлежащим сайту

Comment: Вот к примеру: Есть некое запрещенное заведение. Вы нашли человека который Вас проведет через черный вход туда и обратно. Как Вы думаете, может ли проводник узнать кого он проводит?

Comment: @andreymal есть же sni, днс и факт соединения тцп.

Comment: @eri sni зашифрован, днс зашифрован, тцп подключается к серверам условного cloudflare за которым миллионы сайтов

Comment: где sni зашифрован? кто зашифровал днс? нелегальные сайты не хостятся на cloudflare

Comment: @andreymal https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETGd1.png

Comment: @eri вы где-то проспали последние несколько лет, не читали новости и очень давно не обновляли свою систему, нет никакого смысла показывать wireshark из устаревшей и ненастроенной системы. И абсолютно ничего не мешает нелегальным сйтам сидеть за cloudflare

Comment: @eri вы вот лучше [посмотрите мой wireshark](https://andreymal.org/files/wireshark-esni-test.pcap) и скажите, какой сайт на IP-адресе 104.26.5.124 я посетил? (При захвате пакетов я запускал новый процесс Firefox без предварительного прогрева, DNS-запрос здесь тоже захвачен, ни одного пакета я из захвата не удалил)

Comment: @andreymal  Chrome/94 не такое уж и древнее ПО. я хочу лишь сказать что ваш первый коментарий вкорне неверный. просто полагаться на https не стоит. а по поводу айпишника - опять какие запрещенные сайты на клаудфларе?

Comment: @eri ну вы от вопроса не увиливайте, посмотрите мой трафик и скажите, какой сайт я посетил и какой конкретно захваченный пакет доказывает неверность моего первого комментария

Comment: @andreymal этот сайт должен быть в каком-то списке. дайте список хостов в котором есть этот. сравниваем хеш esni со всеми сайтами из списка - и попался.

Comment: @eri представьте, что вы злой админ впн-сервера, вы не собираетесь спрашивать список хостов у каждого пользователя впн, добудьте этот список самостоятельно и скажите какой сайт я посетил) Но даже если вдруг вы и правы (я это пока не проверял), на замену eSNI придёт ECH и при достаточном его распространении такое уже не прокатит

Comment: както пофик на то что админ увидит какой сайт вы посетили. но вот если задать вопрос по другому: "посещали ли вы порнхаб в рабочее время?", "заходили ли вы на сайт урл которого намалёванно на стене соседнего дома?". абстрактный сайт на клаудфларе не интересен злому админу

Comment: @eri про «пользуясь фактом соединения с IP-адресом» я уже написал в первом комментарии, не знаю почему вы это решили проигнорировать

Answer (score 0):

И да и нет, зависит от того, включили ли они ведение логов.

Если вы используете протокол HTTP, админы видят все, что передается по сети - не только адреса, но и вообще все занные, переданные от вас и к вам.

Если вы используете HTTPS - админы увидят только адрес сайта, но им недоступен URL открываемой страницы и переданные данные.

Аналогично с мессенджерами - некторые мессенджеры позволяют читать на транзитном узле всю переписку (ICQ), некоторые - только сам факт связи с серверами мессенжера (Telegram)

Comment: Есть вариант подделки главной страницы входа(авторизации) подтвердить реальный домен которой в vpn на мой взгляд невозможно (будь то сайт с браузера или приложение на устройствах). Потому говорить что использование https защищает от перехвата логина и пароля в vpn как-то опасно. Так как https будет успешно обрабатываться на сервере vpn после запроса на вход от клиента и уже авторизироваться на проксируемом сервере для того что бы отдать клиенту результат авторизации в соединение в котором он прислал логин и пароль.В итоге выходит 2 https между клиентом и vpn и между vpn и удалённым сервером

Comment: @noname2019 ничего подобного, https ровно один и он защищает соединение между браузером и сайтом, и vpn никак не способен на него повлиять (кроме как прервать соединение). Вы путаете vpn с обычным http-прокси.

Comment: @andreymal расскажите пожалуйста как работает vpn. Что-то я думал всегда что vpn это обычный прокси...

Comment: @noname2019 https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/VPN

Comment: @andreymal почитайте [вот это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80) особенно эту часть "при этом о посредничестве могут как знать, так и не знать обе стороны" и скажите что вы всегда на 100% уверены что используете именно vpn ?

Comment: @noname2019 конечно уверен, потому что я всегда устанавливаю и настраиваю свои собственные vpn-серверы своими собственными руками. Встроенным в браузеры чужим шлаком, в котором под названием vpn подают обычные http-прокси, я не пользуюсь и не собираюсь пользоваться.

Comment: @andreymal ну если свои собственные и сами всё делаете то конечно вопросов нет. Но если взять в общем, вы правильно подметили в сети большинство шлака "как бы vpn" но на самом деле прокси чистой воды.

Comment: @noname2019 - нетушки, невозможно подменить сайт, отдавая через VPN какую-то другую страницу по HTTPS. Потому что для этого нужно иметь возможность зашифровать эту страницу с сертификатом для этого сайта, а это сделать невозможно, так как сертификатом располагает только этот самый сайт.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день) Они могут включать в себя логи посещенных веб-сайтов (однако, это встречается довольно редко) или журналы использования, такие как время, на протяжении которого вы были подключены к VPN, и объем используемой полосы пропускания. Советую прочитать эту статью, там детально описываются все моменты связанные с VPN) https://codeby.net/threads/8-luchshix-vpn-dlja-torrentov-i-p2p-po-sostojaniju-na-2018-god-chast-1.65638/

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin отличная политика - бегать на цирлах вокруг заведомого спамера, на каждый его пост рассказывая, что мол хорошо но не совсем правильно

Comment: @Ипатьев, в моём комментарии процитирована документация. если вы считаете, что документацию следует поправить, создайте, пожалуйста, запрос на мете

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin очень смешно :) робот, которого ты написал чтобы оставлять комменты, явно неудачный. Совсем невпопад